# repeating child with this.props of parent react element

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs, parent-child, repeat

Currently i m working on creating react components, and i need to repeat the child components, based on this.props.value of parent component.
I am struggling to find any good examples.

here is my code

var LiComponent = React.createClass({

```
render:function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <span>{this.props.label}</span>
            <span>{this.props.value}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

var StatsComponent = React.createClass({

```
    getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        value: this.props.value || []
    }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    var data = this.state.value,
        columnName = data[0],
        data = data.slice(1),
        values = data.map(function (o) { return o.value; }),
        labels = data.map(function (o) { return o.label; });
},

shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){

    var data = nextProps.value,
        labels = data.map(function (o) { return o.label; }),
        values = data.map(function (o) { return o.value; });
    return false;

},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div style={style}>
            <LiComponent>
            </LiComponent>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

now, i want to repeat the LiComponent according to the this.props.value of  Stats Component. How should i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push LiComponents to an array, and render these.

Like this,

```
render: function(){
var rows = this.props.value.map(function(row) {
    //Add props to your LiComponent just as you would normally. 
    return <LiComponent />;
});
return (
    <div style={style}>
        {rows}
    </div>
);
}
```